Psychotherapist swaps with a dangerous patient
Years ago, I watched a fantastic drama/thriller movie of a girl who worked in some kind of an institute, probably a mental-illness-prison.
The girl is taking care of the most dangerous patient, who is said to be able to affect his doctor's mind.
When the movie continued, we see parts of her history but the dots are not really connected. However, she start to illuminate and see things that doesn't exist.
Her patient keeps talking about this "Malachi" unfigured person.
I don't remember a lot more, but I do remember that in the end the twist 

 tells that they swap, and she is actually the patient, he is the
 doctor, and Malachi is the brand name of the electric chair producers.
 Thus, all the wierd things she has been seeing, were ACTUAL life in the institute.
 Her brain-made world she created for herself began to collapse when the "patient"
 (who is really her doctor) started a therapy with her in order to reveal that her life were fake. Kind of "Shutter island" but better.

I saw this movie in 2006, so it have to be earlier.
I've been looking for it for ages, and still can not tell which movie is that.

Sounds like Breaking Dawn from 2004. The plot fits (as does the Malachi part).

Dawn, a young medical student is charged with uncovering the murder of a mental patient's mother. The patient, Don, holds many secrets and disturbs Dawn with his insane ramblings. As Dawn continues to investigate the murder, she believes Don's paranoia is out of control at the mention of a menacing figure named Malachi. She begins to question whether Malachi exists when she is stalked by a mysterious figure or if her imagination and Don's craziness are affecting her judgement.

It ends with the twist you described. Here's the trailer:



